# Only use part of data in a .graph file in genealogytree

Tags: genealogytree

In this example I use the same `.graph` file twice, but the second time I only use a part of it. The file `example.formal.graph` in the example is one that comes with the package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}[template=formal graph]
  input{example.formal.graph}
\end{genealogypicture}

\bigskip
Here is the left part again:

\begin{genealogypicture}[
  template=formal graph,
  ignore node={na5},
  options for node={na1, na2}{phantom},
  ignore subtree={fam_C}
  ]
  input{example.formal.graph}
\end{genealogypicture}


\end{document}
```

This yields the following:
[image]

This is approximately what I want, that is to be able to extract just a part of a graph file. But setting phantom for the two uppermost nodes here is a workaround that isn't ideal, at least because that takes up space. I can't ignore those two nodes as well, because then I get a "No g-node" error. Is there a better way to use just a subtree from a graph file?

Comment: Well, I do not know a better way to select a subtree, because a root node cannot really be removed. Alternative, you can try the other way around and save the selected subtree as a single graph. The larger graph can be constructed using `input` (see section 4.9 of the documentation).

Comment: I see. It has often been so practical to use the same graph file for different trees when it was too hard to fit all information in the graph file in one tree. For example I have ignored some nodes and subtrees in one tree that are shown in a complementary tree and used different inserts to have the different trees refer to each other. In a similar vein it would sometimes be nice then to decide to pull out a big subtree and present it on its own, but thinking more about it I guess that that would need a totally new feature, with some option for selecting to "top tree".

Answer (score 1):

I came from the same situation and developed a tool to help me with just that problem. It is called **generations** and available for free on [github.com/jojomi/generations](https://github.com/jojomi/generations). It generates tex files from a database while enabling you to filter the contacts to generate arbitrary trees from a single unchanged source.

It comes with options like freely selecting the **root person** of the tree, limiting the **generations to consider** or the **type of data** to include (no middlenames? sure! no dates of divorces? as you like! no images? your choice!). You can change the **LaTeX templates** used to create the output you need.

The database is a yml file, no GEDCOM support yet (but would technically be possible to develop).

Example for a single database entry:

```
- id: PachGerd1954
  gender: male
  name:
    first:
    - Gerd
    last: Pachowski
  birth:
    date: "1954-07-04"
    place: Bottrop
  mom: PachGise1921
  dad: PachDiet1919
  partners:
  - partner_id: "GöhlMela1954"
    marriage:
      date: "1975-07-01"
    divorce:
      date: "1990-03-09"
```